# Acronym list won't span more than one page

Tags: page-breaking, acronyms

I found this problem by noticing that the acronym package `acro` was inserting a blank page before the acronym list.  I then discovered that not only was it inserting this blank page, but that list of acronyms weren't spanning multiple pages as they should.  See image below:

[image: Acronym list failing to span pages]

I've created a minimum working example which gives me the blank page and also creates the acronym list error.  (Note: If you comment out the acronyms used in the text body one by one, eventually you will reduce the list size such that it fits on one page and the blank page disappears.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{acro}% needs v0.4 of `acro'
\acsetup{
            page-name=Acronyms,
            list-style=tabular,
            list-header=chapter*,
            list-table-width=10cm,
            list-long-format=\capitalisewords
            }
\usepackage{mfirstuc}% provides\capitalisewords

% test acronyms
\DeclareAcronym{aaa}{AAA}{AAA}
\DeclareAcronym{aab}{AAB}{AAB}
\DeclareAcronym{aac}{AAC}{AAC}
\DeclareAcronym{aad}{AAD}{AAD}
\DeclareAcronym{aae}{AAE}{AAE}
\DeclareAcronym{aaf}{AAF}{AAF}
\DeclareAcronym{aag}{AAG}{AAG}
\DeclareAcronym{aah}{AAH}{AAH}
\DeclareAcronym{aai}{AAI}{AAI}
\DeclareAcronym{aaj}{AAJ}{AAJ}
\DeclareAcronym{aak}{AAK}{AAK}
\DeclareAcronym{aal}{AAL}{AAL}
\DeclareAcronym{aam}{AAM}{AAM}
\DeclareAcronym{aan}{AAN}{AAN}
\DeclareAcronym{aao}{AAO}{AAO}
\DeclareAcronym{aap}{AAP}{AAP}
\DeclareAcronym{aaq}{AAQ}{AAQ}
\DeclareAcronym{aar}{AAR}{AAR}
\DeclareAcronym{aas}{AAS}{AAS}
\DeclareAcronym{aat}{AAT}{AAT}
\DeclareAcronym{aau}{AAU}{AAU}
\DeclareAcronym{aav}{AAV}{AAV}
\DeclareAcronym{aaw}{AAW}{AAW}
\DeclareAcronym{aax}{AAX}{AAX}
\DeclareAcronym{aay}{AAY}{AAY}
\DeclareAcronym{aaz}{AAZ}{AAZ}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\printacronyms
\newpage

\acs{aaa}
\acs{aab}
\acs{aac}
\acs{aad}
\acs{aae}
\acs{aaf}
\acs{aag}
\acs{aah}
\acs{aai}

\acs{aaj}
\acs{aak}
\acs{aal}
\acs{aam}
\acs{aan}
\acs{aao}
\acs{aap}
\acs{aaq}

\acs{aar}
\acs{aas}
\acs{aat}
\acs{aau}
\acs{aav}
\acs{aaw}
\acs{aax}
\acs{aay}
\acs{aaz}

\end{document}
```

FYI, I'm using TexNicCenter but have also tested this with LEd and get same problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option `list-style` is setup with `tabular` that cannot span several pages. Package `longtable` can be used to get such a table:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  ...
  list-style=longtable,
  ...
}
```

**Answering the comment:** By default `longtable` is centered horizontally. This is configured by the lengths `\LTleft` and `\LTright`. The table can be put to the left by:

```
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
```

And without the first space of the first column:

```
\setlength{\LTleft}{-\tabcolsep}
```

By grouping the effect can be limited to the acronym list:

```
\begingroup
  \setlength{\LTleft}{-\tabcolsep}
  \printacronyms
\endgroup
```

Comment: Hi @Heiko, thanks for the answer.  When I was choosing list styles before this was an issue, I chose tabular because it looked better - longtable was too indented for me.  Is there a way to modify the list so it shifts things over to the left a bit but doesn't break `acro`?  Thanks

Comment: Fantastic!  You sir, are a champion!  I thank you kindly for your brilliant answer.